# No viable alternative error when using current_timestamp() in pyspark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

### Intro

I want to add a column as current timestamp when executing the select query as below:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.function import current_timestamp

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myapp") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
    .config('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR') \
    .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", 'true') \
    .config("spark.sql.ansi.enabled", 'true') \
    .config("spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy", 'LEGACY') \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

my_df = spark.sql(
"""
SELECT XXX as colA,
       XXX as colB
       current_timestamp() as colC,
       XXX as colD,
FROM   XXX
""")
```

I got the following error like

```
no viable alternative at input `current_timestamp` (line xx,pos xx)
```

I could use `withColumn()` to solve it like

```
my_df = spark.sql(
"""
SELECT XXX as colA,
       XXX as colB
       XXX as colD,
FROM   XXX
""")

my_df  = my_df.withColumn('colC',current_timestamp())
```

### Question

I want to know what is that error means, and is there any solution to use `current_timestamp()` function in my sql query, rather then using `withColumn()` function?

Comment: Isn't it a matter of parenthesis, as it seems you should use `current_timestamp` instead of `current_timestamp()`?

Comment: @Christophe Oh it do solve the problem. Thanks a lot.  May i know why I need to use like that and whats the difference? actually the code with `current_timestamp()` is working in spark2.3 with pyspark2.4 (in GCP), while I am using spark3.1 with pyspark2.12. not sure if it is the versioning issue.

Comment: Well, I do not know, I just searched for [a documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_current_timestamp.asp) on the function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by replacing the `current_timestamp()` to `current_timestamp`.

(using spark 3.1 / pyspark 2.12)